# How can I translate a unit circle that doesn't start at 0, 1?

Tags: trigonometry

Typically the unit circle "starts" at 0, 1. But lets say my vector starts at (x, y), what formula can I use to obtain the typical unit circle vectors $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta$)?

Comment: If I well understand you, the "typical" unit circle parametrization $t\mapsto(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ starts at $(1,0)$, and you would like to find parametrizations starting at other points of the circle?

Comment: Consider $f(t)=(\cos{(t+\theta)}, \sin{(t+\theta}))$.

Comment: @Balloon Yes, exactly!

Comment: In this case, the above comment by @JohnDouma is answering you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may introduce a phase  shift to start at whatever point that you like.

For example $$( x,y)= ( \cos(\theta + \pi/6), \sin (\theta + \pi/6) )$$ starts at  $$(\cos(\pi/6), \sin ( \pi/6) )$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ with $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ describes a unit circle centered atbthe origin from $(1,0)$ counterclockwise.

To start from a generic point $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$ we need to take $\theta\in[\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi]$ such that

- $x=\cos \theta_0$
- $y=\sin \theta_0$